# How to have netrw ignore executables?

Tags: netrw

When I use `netrw` with the `:Explore` command I see that binary/executable files are highlighted in orange and have a little `*` start next to them, so I guess it can recognize them without having to rely on their extension.

How do I make `netrw` ignore executables files by default when it shows me the list of files in the current directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netrw supports hiding entries in the list by allowing you to set a regular expression [hiding list](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-ctrl-h).

Slightly surprisingly, the pattern you set here is matched against the entire displayed entry which *includes* the `*` star you mention (rather than the actual file name), so you can set up an expression to look for entries that end with `*`:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide = '\*$'
```

With this in your `.vimrc`, vim should enter the hiding mode by default and will then display this in its [banner](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-I):

```
"   Hiding:        \*$
```

You can press [`a`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-a) to rotate through the three hiding modes: "show all", "show non-hidden", and "show hidden".

The simple expression above gets you 75% of the way there, matching executables in 3 out of [netrw's 4 listing styles](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-i). However, the `long` listing includes even more information after the file's name, so something more complicated is required. A quick hack that is likely to work for almost all file names is to search for either the end of the line or for two spaces after the `*`:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide = '\*\($\|\s\s\)'
```